# Unwanted spaces in aux file

Tags: auxiliary-files

Suppose I want to write the following to the `.aux`-file

`\gdef\hello{\world\foobar}`

And I do it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\auxdef#1#2{
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string#1{\unexpanded{#2}}}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \def\world{world}
    \def\foobar{foo bar}
    \auxdef\hello{\world\foobar}
    \ifcsname hello\endcsname%
        \hello
    \else%
        not set yet
    \fi
\end{document}
```

Then running `pdflatex` once and checking the `.aux`-file, it shows:

```
\relax 
\gdef\hello{\world \foobar }
```

There are now two spaces that I didn't explicitly insert anywhere: one between `\world` and `\foobar` and another one betwenn `\foobar` and `}`.

The questions are: where does the spaces come from? How can they be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spaces are added by `\write`: TeX *always* adds a space after a control word during `\write`; such spaces are harmless when reading but are essential in case you have

```
\write\file{\relax x}
```

because the space after `\relax` (or any other control word that's unexpandable or made such, in your case by `\unexpanded`) would not even be seen and, if TeX didn't add the space you'd end up with `\relaxx`.

Note that `\detokenize` does the same, because it is implemented with the same code that's used for `\write`.

Those spaces do nothing bad, unless you happen to read a file when the space has a different category code than 10.

Comment: As I wrote below @Jhor's answer: a problem could arise with the space between `\world` and `}`: `\def\name{andreas }\name~strauman` is not the same as `\def\name{andreas}\name~strauman`. When `\name` is intended to be an end-user command, it could definitely matter!

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman I can't understand what you're saying: `\name~strauman` and `\name<space>~strauman` are perfectly equivalent.

Comment: Notice the difference in `\def\name`! There is a space at the end of the definition.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman “TeX always adds a space after a control word”. Is `andreas` a control word?

Comment: Oh, never mind. I thought that `\name ~strauman` and `\name~strauman` would produce different results!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the `\immediate\write\@auxout` does that.

But there is absolutely no need to remove them as a LaTeX command (like your `\world`) always gobbles the (regular) space that follows it. Hence the result of `\hello{\world\foobar}` and `\hello{\world \foobar }` is expected to be exactly the same.